# Redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com with SSL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, lets-encrypt

Sitegound.com suggests the following code to transfer to ssl

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

there is a second option to do the same:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule .* http%1://www.domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Some people also check for the ssl port

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
```

Which is a better way, can someone please tell?

and how to add a second condition to transfer from domain.com to www.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
```

OR should I use domain forwarding from the cpanel for forwarding to www version and just use the .htaccess for ssl
Can I just add the condition above the ssl condition?

The result I want is 
Form 
    http:// OR
    https:// OR
    http://www
to
    https://www.domain.com
with minimum redirects and fastest load time.

Answer (score 1):

Whats the point of doing that? if you a TLS certificate at domain.com but no certificate at www.domain.com the moment the browser reads the certificate from www.domain.com it will trigger a certificate alert.

This is the way is supposed to work. You might want to consider a wildcard or in case a SAN certificate for your needs.
please refer to documentation of a Certificate Authority (CA) letsencrypt for more references on this procedure.

[LetsEncrypt community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/grouping-www-example-com-and-example-com-domains/6255/9)

Answer (score 0):

well instead of playing with htaccess ..

Login to the Cpanel of the website 
click on redirects 
In redirect screen .. Set the type of redirect to permanent 
on the next drop down select the domain 
in redirects to window put https://www.domainname.com

and then click on Add

done.